# Fix Primary Parition to Become Bootable

Tags: arch-linux, partition

Beware, noob question here... Whilst installing Arch Linux for a second time, I forgot to set the first partition with the bootable flag. I do not want to lose any data, but how can I add the bootable flag to the partition? So far, I've used fdisk, but it seems to bring an error upon trying to add the bootable flag.

```
[ arch /boot ]# fdisk /dev/sda1

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.38.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

This disk is currently in use - repartitioning is probably a bad idea.
It's recommended to umount all file systems, and swapoff all swap
partitions on this disk.

The device contains 'ext4' signature and it will be removed by a write command. See fdisk(8) man page and --wipe option for more details.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xfaeee4ac.

Command (m for help): print
Disk /dev/sda1: 500 MiB, 524288000 bytes, 1024000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xfaeee4ac

Command (m for help): a
No partition is defined yet!

Command (m for help):
```

Then using parted, I also receive a similar error (thinking that it never/incorrectly partitioned `/dev/sda1`):

```
[ blackarch /boot ]# parted /dev/sda1
GNU Parted 3.5
Using /dev/sda1
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/sda1: 524MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  524MB  524MB  ext4

(parted) set /dev/sda1 boot                                               
align-check  disk_toggle  mklabel      mktable      print        rescue       resizepart   select       toggle       version
disk_set     help         mkpart       name         quit         resize       rm           set          unit                
(parted) set /dev/sda1 set boot on
Error: Partition doesn't exist.
(parted)
```

What's the fix here? I'm sure it's very simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you run a partitioning tool, you should use a whole-disk device like `/dev/sda` instead of a device referring to a particular partition, like `/dev/sda1`.

Otherwise, you will effectively be asking the tool to build a second partition table inside a partition. You certainly can do that if you wish, but it's not very useful except in very specific circumstances, e.g. when you are planning to use a partition as a virtual disk in a Virtual Machine, and want to pre-partition the virtual disk before the VM is fully installed.

A partition table usually lies outside the actual partitions it controls. So, to set the **bootable** flag on `/dev/sda1`, you'll need to do either:

```
fdisk /dev/sda
```

or:

```
parted /dev/sda
```

If you are planning to use the GRUB bootloader and install it into the Master Boot Record, note that the code that normally checks for a partition's boot flag is in the boot code of the standard Windows Master Boot Record. When you install GRUB into the MBR, that code is replaced with GRUB's code, which will *completely ignore any boot flags* anyway.

So if you plan to use GRUB, setting the boot flag will not be necessary and you can skip that step entirely, unless your system's BIOS specifically checks for that flag (which would be somewhat unusual).

Comment: Well I have GRUB installed (verifiable via mounting the EFI partition), however my system (Dell Latitude machine) is not picking the boot option even after changing the BIOS settings to allow it... How can I fix this?

Comment: Oh, it's an UEFI system? That means you can forget anything I said about the MBR, as it's irrelevant to UEFI. With UEFI, the important things are that the ESP partition has a correct type (although `parted` represents it with the `boot` and `esp` "flags"), and that the NVRAM boot variables have been set correctly. Use `efibootmgr -v` to check the boot variables, and if necessary, other options of `efibootmgr` to change them. You might want to open a new question with the `efibootmgr -v` output included if you still have trouble.

Comment: If using UEFI, best to also use gpt partitioning. Ubuntu allows MBR(msdos) with UEFI and probably should not, not sure about other distributions. Windows requires gpt with UEFI boot. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR

Comment: I ended up reinstalling as other parts of the installation were not correct either. Thanks for the help :despair: